# NSImage returns 0x0 when there is space in the file name

Tags: cocoa

I used the codes below to load image

```
NSURL *url=[NSURL URLWithString:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"file://home/%@", filename]]; 
NSImage *image = [[[NSImage alloc] initWithContentsOfURL:url] autorelease];
```

but I found that if there is a space in the filename, such as

@"a b.jpg"

image returns 0x0

Welcome any comment

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When creating URLs pointing to file system paths, one should use `+fileURLWithPath:` or `-initFileURLWithPath:`. Replace:

```
NSURL *url=[NSURL URLWithString:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"file://home/%@", filename]];
```

with:

```
NSURL *url=[NSURL fileURLWithPath:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"/home/%@", filename]];
```

And, in general, one should use `-[NSString stringByAppendingPathComponent]` when composing strings that represent paths. This method takes care of placing a solidus `/` when appropriate:

```
NSString *fullPath = [[@"/home" stringByAppendingPathComponent:filename] autorelease];
NSURL *url = [NSURL fileURLWithPath:fullPath];
```